# Правильная выборка данных

Tags: php

Доброе время суток, вопрос заключается в том, как логически сделать нечто подобное?

Врач работает в двух клиниках, у каждой клиники есть своя цена приема данного врача, на странице каталог отображается вот такая информация:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вариант который я вижу, это собрать массив клиник с ценами у конкретного врача, а далее

```
<?php foreach ($doctor['clinic'] as $clinic) { ?>
<?php foreach ($clinic['offer'] as $offer) { ?>
<?php echo $offer['price']; ?>
<?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Только вот все равно не понимаю, как добиться того, чтобы показывалась только одна цена выбраной по умолчанию клиники в поле select (Выбора клиники)

Как вариант break, но не красиво ведь...

Comment: Если на странице нужна одна цена то и из БД тащите одну цену, т.е. выбранная в селекте клиника должна накладывать соответствующее ограничивающее условие в sql-запросе

Comment: Или как вариант тащите на клиента все цены в виде массива со связками с клиниками, что бы выбор клиники прямо в браузере менял подсвеченную цену (но это уже на javascript конечно)